# How to extract values from a hidden table using xpath in selenium webdriver (java)

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I want to extract the values from the "From" drop down of http://www.makemytrip.com/flights/ and then compare it with a particular search string to find if the string exist in the values from the drop down. But I am unable to extract the values as these fields are hidden. It is an autocomplete dropdown.

The html part of the drop down

```
   <div class="container">
<div class="search_selector" style="display: none;">
<div class="col-xs-12">
 <div class="city_sel_top">
 <div class="top_cities_scroll" style="margin-top: -5px;">
    <ul id="near_button" class="top_cities_list" style="width: 98%;">
    <ul class="from_city_list top_cities_list" style="width: 98%; display: none;">
        <li class="top_cities_heading text-right">Top Domestic Cities</li>
        <li id="DEL|Y|New Delhi|India">
           <a class="from_city_value1" href="javascript:void(0);">New Delhi, India (DEL)</a>
                  </li>
        <li id="DEL|Y|New Delhi|India">
           <a class="from_city_value1" href="javascript:void(0);">New Delhi, India (DEL)</a>
                 </li>
        <li id="BOM|Y|Mumbai|India">
            <a class="from_city_value2" href="javascript:void(0);">Mumbai, India (BOM)</a>
                  </li>
        <li id="BLR|Y|Bangalore|India">
             <a class="from_city_value3" href="javascript:void(0);">Bangalore, India (BLR)</a>
                 </li
```

>
......

I tried :

```
WebDriver driver;
  List<WebElement> li = driver.findElements( By.xpath("//div/div[2]/ul[2]/li/a"));
```

This gives me a no such element exception as the first li element under ul[2] does not have a 'a' element under it. I want to get the 'a' element starting from the second li element.

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath is too strict! Use `By.tagName("a")`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want 'a' of the first item, then I think SiKing's solution is the best. But it you have to use xpath, then I think it should be the following:

```
//div/div/div/div[2]/ul[2]/li[2]/a
```